# How can I possibly include a .inc from MASM32 in VS Code?

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

My .asm code goes:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap: none
include windows.inc
include kernel32.inc
include user32.inc
includelib kernel32.lib
includelib user32.lib
.data
szCaption db "Hello", 0
szText db "Hello World!", 0
.code
main PROC
INVOKE MessageBox, NULL, addr szText, addr szCaption, MB_OK
INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

But the following error occurred:

```
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1993.  All rights reserved.
     Invoking: ML.EXE /I. /Zm /c /Ta D:\TEST.ASM 
     Assembling: D:\TEST.ASM
    D:\TEST.ASM(4): fatal error A1000: cannot open file : windows.inc
```

I have installed extensions: MASM/TASM, masm-code, MASM runner and code runner according to different posts I have found.
Plus, I have already installed masm32 at C:\masm32 under instructions.
I have added my environment variables: Path:(\masm32, \masm32\bin)

But seems that my VS Code still fails to reach masm32.
What else should I do to fix?
My OS is Win10.

Comment: You need to find some setting in Visual Studio where you can add additional include paths that will be passed to `ml` (either that or use full paths in your `.asm` file, i.e.. `include \masm32\include\windows.inc` etc).